# How to define a macro globally in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macros

I want to define a macro globally. I want to override `NSLocalizedString()` throughout my whole project. Is that possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Declare the macro in the `#ifdef __OBJC__` section of your AppName-Prefix.pch.

Comment: But be careful about "renaming" a common class, etc.  Such things can bite you in unexpected ways.

Comment: Thx. I'll override NSLocalizedString to call the very same function. I'll just change the Bundle it will be called on since i'm trying to achieve in-app localization (switching languages on-the-fly within the app). You still think this could cause problems? Anyways I'm alarmed :)

Answer (score 5):

You define your macro in some header file. You place this header file in `*.pch` file (prefix header file). Search for "prefix" in build settings for your target. Make sure your `*.pch` file is used.