# Macro constant for something like status bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I know how to define constants and macros using C. Is there any way to define a constant in Objective-C like this:

```
#define STATUSBAR_HEIGHT [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Remember, Objective-C *is* C...any valid C is also valid Objective-C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes thats pretty much it. For example you want to open a url then -

```
#define OPEN_URL(urlString) [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]
```

Put this in a file like `utils.h` and import that header file for this macro to be available. But in a large code base it is irritating to be importing in each file, You could declare a global macro in the `#ifdef __OBJC__` section of your AppName-Prefix.pch. Now you need not import in each file...

Comment: It's extremely important to note that the _value_ is not constant. Macros are just a rewriting of the source code. At runtime, all those method calls still happen, and the value of the macro may be different each time it's used.

Comment: +1, and nice to include the global-macro info as well. I saw it in a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202526/how-to-define-a-macro-globally-in-objective-c?rq=1) but having both how-to and global-scope in a single answer will likely help future readers, especially with the title on this question.