# iOS - Is it possible to make a macro globally available without importing the file in which it is defined every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, logging, macros

I want to define a logging macro that I can use in all my source files, but I don't want to import the file in which I defined the macro every time? So, I am just curios whether it is possible to make a macro globally available without importing the file in which it is defined every time?

Comment: Import the required files in `AppName-Prefix.pch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the macro in the `#ifdef __OBJC__` section of your AppName-Prefix.pch.

Source [How to define a macro globally in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202526/how-to-define-a-macro-globally-in-objective-c)

Comment: Instead of answering one liner, and adding nothing more, you could have rested with your "possible dupe" comment :)

Comment: he needed some points